# Test file write in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I am developing a rails API application for an iphone app. Some of the endpoints lead to functions that write data into a file and stores it in a directory. Everything works fine but every time I run a test for one of these specific endpoints a file is written. Is it possible to get the file to automatically be removed once the test is complete?

More info:
I am using RSpec with shoulda_matchers and FactoryGirl in case it is any use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the file in an `after` block, e.g.

```
context :foo do
  let(:filename) { '/foo/bar/baz/qux.txt' }

  it { ... }

  after do
    FileUtil.rm filename
  end
end
```

Comment: I get this error:

NoMethodError:
undefined method `after' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_3::Nested_1:0x007fdd0b3421d8>

Any Idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: @ShEsKo, try `after(:each)` or `after(:all)` or `after(:suite)`.

Comment: still no luck :/ @Mori